# Does anyone have any stats or thoughts on Performance of WPF on 64bit OS?

Tags: .net, wpf, 64-bit

I see lot of new machines and laptops now having 64 bit hardware and provided all drivers are correct, will WPF and corresponding .NET will run any faster on 64 bit machines? I dont see any documentation about .NET or WPF on 64 bit anywhere, but I would like to know the difference. I see that .NET has no specific API for 64bit architecture, it is a neutral platform, but what about WPF?

Comment: WPF is part of the .Net Framework so you have, in essence, answered your own question. To take it further, badly written apps will run slow on 32-bit platforms as well as 64-bit platforms. A well written 32-bit app could outperform a 64-bit app if it was written better than the 64-bit version. The real benefit of 64-bit apps is address space, i.e. your app needs more than 2GB (I think that's the scope) of working RAM.

Comment: WPF does use native API like Desktop Window Manager etc which I believe is little dependent on platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the framework is compiled to take advantage of extra instructions, there might be a slight performance increase but 64bit is more about address space than extra speed.

And WPF/Avalon is a subset of .NET v3 so, yes, it is neutral too.

Edit: [Here's a good thread on 64bit JIT performance.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432/64bit-net-performance-tuning) (but note that the answers are a year and a half old - one would hope MS have improved things for 64bit users)

Answer (score 0):

WPF application run as 64bit processes on 64bit OS (unless compiled specifically to target only x86) just like any other .net application.