# OutOfMemoryException on declaration of Large Array

Tags: c#

I have to create a fairly large double array 12000ish x 55000ish. Unfortunately, I get an out of memory exception. I used to develop in Java and could change the memory settings. Is this possible with C# or is it just impossible? I am using VS 2008.

Comment: I would suggest you consider an "out of main memory" data structure (i.e. database). Why do you have to store such a large double array?

Comment: I did chuckle at the choice of word "fairly" too.

Comment: No worries I will persist stuff in a database.

Comment: Maybe one could also solve the problem when setting the `LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE`-PE-Flag

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Each `double` is 8 bytes, so you're trying to allocate a single array with just over 5GB. The CLR has a per-object limit of around 2GB IIRC, even for a 64-bit CLR. In other words, it's not the total amount of memory available that's the problem (although obviously you'll have issues if you *don't* have enough memory), but the per-object size.

I suggest you split it into smaller arrays, perhaps behind a facade of some description. I don't believe there's any way to workaround that limit for a single array.

EDIT: You *could* go for an array of arrays - aka a *jagged array*:

```
double[][] array = new double[12000][];
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    array[i] = new double[55000];
}
```

Would that be acceptable to you?

(You can't use a rectangular array (`double[,]`) as that would have the same per-object size problem.)

Comment: Instead of a single array of doubles, I think he means 2D array

Comment: Virtual Memory is not the issue. You're trying to allocate 5GB of memory with a 2GB limit. :)

Comment: Also, due to memory fragmentation, OP might experience problems as soon as they try to allocate a contiguous block of several hundreds of Mb.

Comment: @Jon The array will be quite sparse (document by word matrix) so jagged array might be an option. have to implemnet a db/nhibernate solution anyway soon though as things get bigger. thanks for your input!

Comment: @csetzkorn If the data is very sparse then perhaps they shouldn't be in an array at all.  Use a `Dictionary<int, double>` to store the data.  It's probably going to use less space so long as about half of the values are empty.

Comment: @Servy: Mapping each (x, y) to a single int? Yes, that's an option. I think I'd probably use a custom value type instead though.

Comment: @JonSkeet If there are sections of contiguous data separated by large sections of contiguous nothingness, then a jagged array would be great (essentially the model paged memory uses)  If the large sections of nothingness/stuff aren't contiguous then it doesn't work so well.

Comment: @JonSkeet I assumed (incorrectly it seems) his data was single dimensional.  If it's multi-dimensional then you'd want something like a `Dictionary<Point, double>` instead, yes.

Comment: @Servy: Given the acceptance, I suspect the OP was actually fine with the fact that the jagged array used quite a lot of memory. These days 5GB isn't *that* much :)

Comment: Is that 2 GB limit more because of the fact that it will always be difficult to get 2 GB continugous memory blocks in RAM or 2 GB memory space for a single object of an application simply looks unviable for 32 bit OS. I'm of the later opinion. 32 bit OS can address only  4 GB of memory. There is already 3 GB barrier while addressing main memory, then you have OS reserved space , then  you have got running application space. I believe even if CLR had initially allowed to go over 2 GB per object it would have never been viable.

Answer (score 11):

Since you can't create objects larger than 2GB you can try to use [MemoryMappedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) to work with chunk of memory of the required size.

```
var data = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("big data", 12000L * 55000L);
var view = data.CreateViewAccessor();
var rnd = new Random();

for (var i = 0L; i < 12000L; ++i)
{
    for (var j = 0L; j < 55000L; ++j)
    {
        var input = rnd.NextDouble();
        view.Write<double>(i * 55000L + j, ref input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Providing that your total memory is sufficient, you can prevent Out of memory exceptions resulting from LOH fragmentation by creating a bunch of smaller arrays, and wrapping them in a single `IList<T>`, or some other indexed interface.

Here is a link which describes it:

[`BigArray<T>, getting around the 2GB array size limit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/joshwil/bigarrayt-getting-around-the-2gb-array-size-limit)

Credits: [this post (C# chunked array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088413/c-chunked-array/4088474#4088474).

Answer (score 0):

Well either you are out of memory (close some programs) or you're hitting the memory allocation limit (about 2Gb), this memory needs to be a contiguous block. You could use a 64bit machine in which case you'll have more memory available or I think you can make the application large address aware (googling will tell you how to do this if it's possible in this case).

Believe you add a /3GB switch to the Boot.ini file for the large address awareness.