# Jagged array OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, jagged-arrays

I'm trying to initialize a jagged array of 120 000 x 4600 for a data mining algorithm but I have an  `OutOfMemoryException` exception

```
double[][] array = new double[120000][];
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    array[i] = new double[4600];
}
```

it throws when `i` is around 49 000

I know .Net is limited to 2GB per object, but I thought that the array here would be a list of addresses to an array of double. So it wouldn't be a big single object.

I thought that's why Jon Skeet suggests an jagged array for this question
[OutOfMemoryException on declaration of Large Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815461/outofmemoryexception-on-declaration-of-large-array)

I don't think that I understand his answer.

Is it one big object and if it's not why does it throw an exception.

Thank you

Comment: Did you compile as 64 bits? Also make sure that "Prefer 32-Bit" isn't set in the Build options.

Comment: 4,600 * 49,000 (the iteration at which it throws) is 225,400,000 elements. That multiplied by 8 bytes (the size of a `double`) is 1,803,200,000 bytes. And you don't know why it throws `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: `4600 * 120000 * 8 bytes = 4.11 GB`

Comment: yeah, I thought it would be 120000 arrays of 4200, instead of one big 4gb object

Comment: To all the people saying he will have a 4GB data structute, that is only true if he declared the array `[,]`, by making a jagged array with `[][]` it is one array of `120000` references and `120000` arrays that are `4600 * 8` bytes large. Marc, you are correct, the commenters are wrong.

Comment: @Scott The commenters saying that you have one single 4 GB data structure are wrong, yes - only that there are _no_ such commenters.

Comment: @DanielDaranas The people I was addressing have deleted their comments.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thank you! that was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is 32-bit application, You are rightly getting `OutOfMemoryException`. For this size requirements you need to target X64.

At i = 49000,
Total memory = 49000*4600*8 = 1803200000 bytes = ~1.68GB.

Now For 32-bit applications (targeted X86), Total User Memory avaiable to an application is 2GB (unless the application is [Large address aware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z.aspx), [.NET application - Large Address Aware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/203797te.aspx) and OS is also enabled for this. [Ex: (for)Vista](http://www.autodesk.in/adsk/servlet/ps/dl/item?siteID=123112&id=9583842&linkID=9240617). Then there is some CLR overhead, then application overhead.

At i = 120000, You need total memory as 
Total memory = 120000*4600*8 = 1803200000 bytes = ~4.11GB.  (Platform target should be X64)

Comment: Also, the address space is usually pretty fragmented in 32 bit processes which limits the size of the biggest contiguous block.