# Maximum number of elements in a 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to make an 2d array, but c# won't let me and says that it is too big, any ideas how to make it work?

```
int[,] arrayName = new int[37153,18366];
```

Comment: This array need 2.6GB memory (37153 x 18366 x 4 Bytes)

Comment: Why do you need such a big array in memory? Can't you use a database instead and get only useful data in memory?

Comment: Take a look at [What is the maximum length of an array in .NET on 64-bit Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338778/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-array-in-net-on-64-bit-windows)

Comment: If you are running on a 64 bit machine and using .Net 4.5 or later, you could try setting [`<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338778/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-array-in-net-on-64-bit-windows).

Answer (score 3):

The max theoretical size of an int array is 2147483647 i.e. `int[] array = new int[2147483647]` but the probleming you're having here is that the computer runs of out memory.

Read this for explanation and tips on how to solve this:
[OutOfMemoryException on declaration of Large Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815461/outofmemoryexception-on-declaration-of-large-array)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using the complete range of the array (which is in your case 2,7GB of RAM), you could use a `Dictionary`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Alternative: Create a [][] Array. In this case you must initialize each row.
But you can access each cell easy with `arrayName[row][col]`.

```
    int[][] arrayName = new int[37153][];
    for(int i=0; i<arrayName.Length; i++)
        arrayName[i] = new int[18366];
```

Comment: Unfortunately,I do need to use the whole range of the array.